# Is there any way to get a screenshots also from processes when they are mininimized?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Today now I can get screenshots of minimized windows of applications.
For example, if I open Paint I will see a screenshot of the Paint main window even if the Paint is minimized.

This is the class that get the WindowsSnap it's a bit long code so i added it to pastebin.com [WindowSnap.cs](http://pastebin.com/Cpe242BA)

And the class WindowSnapCollection also added it to pastebin.com [WindowSnapCollection.cs](http://pastebin.com/SFPVymdv)

And in form1 top and constructor I'm doing:
Variables:

```
private Graphics g;
private Image img;
private Image imgClone;
```

Then in the constructor:

```
        img = new Bitmap(pictureBoxSnap.Width, pictureBoxSnap.Height);
        imgClone = new Bitmap(pictureBoxSnap.Width, pictureBoxSnap.Height);
        Graphics g;
        using (g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
        {
            g.Clear(Color.White);
        }

        pictureBoxSnap.Image = img;

        this.listBoxSnap.Items.AddRange(WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).ToArray());
        for (int i = listBoxSnap.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            string tt = listBoxSnap.Items[i].ToString();
            if (tt.Contains(" ,"))
            {
                listBoxSnap.Items.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
        buttonSnap.Enabled = true;

        string[] myList = new string[listBoxSnap.Items.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < listBoxSnap.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            string tt = listBoxSnap.Items[i].ToString();
            int index = tt.LastIndexOf(",");
            myList[i] = tt.Substring(0, index);
        }
```

In the end, I get a list of open applications window screenshots minimized applications

And I have 65 processes running now I wonder my question is if I can get somehow also the screenshots of the minimized processes? And not all the applications.

Comment: This is a screenshot that show my program when it's running. Now i can get all minimized apps windows screenshots. But i want to know if and how it's possible to get also all processes for example i have now 65 running processes so to get the screenshots of this 65 processes or at least those with graphical interface. http://postimg.org/image/r1hz40v8d/

Comment: Can you enumerate the processes using `Process.GetProcesses();` and only list those processes that have a non-zero main window handle, e.g. `p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero`?

Comment: Loathing yes i did i'm getting 24 intptrs

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the processes, and call the API function [`IsIconic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for each valid hWnd.  For example:

```
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    if (p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        if (IsIconic(p.MainWindowHandle))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Window: {0} Is minimized", p.MainWindowTitle);
        }
    }
}
```

Where `IsIconic` is defined by the following p/Invoke signature.

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);
```